# How to get next arrat for =VLOOKP?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am making Vlookup for my excel file =VLOOKUP('Fail1'!A4;'Fail1'!A3:E1048576;1;TRUE) but when i copy to next row it shows #REF!. And i need to copy allway down for my file.

I want to take From Fail1 some table part and insert into FAIL2 with VLOOKUP
.

Comment: Use `A:A` instead of `A3:E1048576`?

Comment: A:E? because this is marked table

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, typo.